# How to add errorbars to stripplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, errorbar, stripplot

I've run into some difficulty adding error bars to my plots I've created in Python using Seaborn.

I currently have a data frame in a 'csv' format;

```
TSMdatabase = 'TSMvsRunmaster.csv';
tsmdf = pd.read_csv(TSMdatabase, sep=',');
```

The Dataframe has this heading format:

```
Run,TSMX_Value,TSMX_Error,TSMX+1_Value,TSMX+1_Error,Source
```

I then use a for loop to read in the different TSM values:

```
TSM = ['001', '002', '003', '004', '010', '011', '012', 
   '013', '016', '017', '101', '102', '104', '105', '106']

for x in TSM:
     tsm = x
```

And then finally I plot giving me:

```
plt.figure()
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
ax = sns.stripplot(x="Run", y='TSM'+str(tsm)+'_Value', hue="Source", data=tsmdf, 
                   jitter=True, palette="Set2", split=True)
plt.xticks(rotation=40)
plt.title('Run TSM'+str(tsm)+' Comparison')
plt.show()
```

Plot for certain TSM without Error Bars
[image: Plot for certain TSM without Error Bars]

If I then try to add error bars, I end up with just one Error Bar in the middle of each sub data set:

[image]

where each source, Python and Matlab actually has their own errors in the data frame!

Does anybody have any ideas! Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: First, you need to include how you put the errorbars to the plot, *'I then try to add error bars'* could mean anything. Second, using a [mcve] would increase your chances of getting help dramatically. So if it is possible to reproduce the behaviour using some mockup data, please provide the corresponding code.

Answer (score 20):

Plotting the mean + error is more suitable for `sns.pointplot()` than `sns.stripplot()`. This is indicated in the Seaborn documentation:

> [**sns.pointplot**](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html?highlight=pointplot#seaborn.pointplot)
>   Show point estimates and confidence intervals using scatter plot glyphs. A point plot represents an estimate of central tendency for a numeric variable by the position of scatter plot points and provides some indication of the uncertainty around that estimate using error bars.
>
> [**sns.stripplot**](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html?highlight=stripplot#seaborn.stripplot)
>   Draw a scatterplot where one variable is categorical. A strip plot can be drawn on its own, but it is also a good complement to a box or violin plot in cases where you want to show all observations along with some representation of the underlying distribution.

If you have access to all observations, and not just the mean + error, what you want can be achieved simply by:

```
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
sns.pointplot('sex', 'tip', hue='smoker',
    data=tips, dodge=True, join=False)
```

[image]

You can change the type of confidence interval from the default 95% with the `ci` parameter:

```
sns.pointplot('sex', 'tip', hue='smoker',
    data=tips, dodge=True, join=False, ci='sd')
```

[image]

In the above, Seaborn calculated the measurements of error and central tendency. It is a little trickier if you already have these precalculated since there is currently not possible to use `sns.pointplot()` with a precalculated error bar. I add the errors using `plt.errorbar()` after plotting the means using `sns.pointplot()`:

```
ax = sns.pointplot('sex', 'tip', hue='smoker',
    data=tips, dodge=True, join=False, ci=None)

# Find the x,y coordinates for each point
x_coords = []
y_coords = []
for point_pair in ax.collections:
    for x, y in point_pair.get_offsets():
        x_coords.append(x)
        y_coords.append(y)

# Calculate the type of error to plot as the error bars
# Make sure the order is the same as the points were looped over
errors = tips.groupby(['smoker', 'sex']).std()['tip']
colors = ['steelblue']*2 + ['coral']*2
ax.errorbar(x_coords, y_coords, yerr=errors,
    ecolor=colors, fmt=' ', zorder=-1)
```

[image]

You could also use matplotlib directly for the entire plot, If you supply the  x-positions manually, similar to [this example](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/errorbar_demo.html).

Comment: Regarding the latter option with plt.errorbar: the given code to get `x_coords` and `y_coords` yields a whole bunch of "masked" entries with the current version of seaborn (for my use case, at least). Adding `x_coords = [x_coord for x_coord in x_coords if not np.ma.is_masked(x_coord)]` (and similarly for `y_coords`) seems to resolve that issue.