# seaborn stripplot: custom, non-overlapping markers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, google-maps-markers

This question is related to [How can I plot mean and standard deviation error bars stripplot or swarmplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76307846/14553595), but not redundant, as it treats a different issue. My suggestion to the developer is to implement a `markers`parameter, see https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/3587. But maybe there is already a way implemented to solve this problem.

I have the following example data called `test.csv`:

```
r2_score,featureset,retailer
0.7055950484,c,S
0.942584686,c,K
0.8651950609,c,B
0.9051873402,c,H
0.5877088336,c,P
0.7944303127,c,O
0.6370605237,fc,S
0.9755270173,fc,K
0.9065356558,fc,B
0.921142567,fc,H
0.5798048892,fc,P
0.6580349995,fc,O
0.7217345443,f,S
0.9755270173,f,K
0.8839177116,f,B
0.921142567,f,H
0.5070612616,f,P
0.6580349995,f,O
0.5678318495,s,S
0.9637899061,s,K
0.9369641498,s,B
0.9297479733,s,H
0.5029283363,s,P
0.6580349995,s,O
0.5678318495,sc,S
0.9729308458,sc,K
0.8471079755,sc,B
0.9297479733,sc,H
0.497615548,sc,P
0.6580349995,sc,O
0.6624239947,w,S
0.889206858,w,K
0.7810312601,w,B
0.8562172874,w,H
0.4446346851,w,P
0.6580349995,w,O
```

And the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 12]

test = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

# Calculate mean and standard deviation
mean_data = test.groupby('featureset')['r2_score'].mean().values
std_data = test.groupby('featureset')['r2_score'].std().values
colorlist = ['olivedrab', 'seagreen', 'lightseagreen', 'steelblue', 'royalblue', 'slateblue']

p = sns.stripplot(x="featureset",
                  y="r2_score",
                  hue="retailer",
                  data=test,
                  marker='^',
                  size=8,
                  palette=colorlist
                  )

for i, feature in enumerate(featuresets):
    plt.errorbar(x=feature, y=mean_data[i], yerr=std_data[i], color='black', fmt='_', capsize=3)
    
plt.legend(title='Retailer')
sns.move_legend(p, loc="upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))

p.set(xlabel='Featureset', ylabel='R2 Score')
```

With this, I got the following plot:
[image: Plot]

I want the markers to be different for each retailer, to be more precisely, I want the markers to be the letter of the retailer. E.g. `seaborn.swarmplot` hast the markers parameter, to which I could pass the list with my markers. `seaborn.stripplot` does not have this parameter but it would be super useful, as all other methods do not produce the wanted results. For example does using a for loop lead to an overlapping of the markers and the errorbar:

```
ordered_list=['S', 'K', 'B', 'H', 'P', 'O']
retailer_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
colorlist = ['olivedrab', 'seagreen', 'lightseagreen', 'steelblue', 'royalblue', 'slateblue']
for i in range(len(ordered_list)):    
        p = sns.stripplot(x=x_axis,
                          y="r2_score",
                          hue=hue,
                          data=test.loc[test[hue] == ordered_list[i]],
                          marker='$' + retailer_list[i] + '$',
                          size=20,
                          palette=[colorlist[i]])
```

[image: Plot_2]